# How to add buffer-local mapping only if not in command-line-window

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd

I've tried this

```
au BufWinEnter * if &l:buftype != 'nofile' | map <buffer> <CR> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix) | endif
```

but somehow this isn't working (easymotion isn't working). While this works

```
au BufWinEnter * map <buffer> <CR> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that `| endif` is in the `{rhs}` of the mapping command `:map`. To remove it, you could wrap the mapping in a chain and execute it, maybe like this:

```
au BufWinEnter * if &l:buftype != 'nofile' | exe "map <buffer> \<CR> \<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)" | endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggling the global mapping, you could also define a (command-line window) buffer-local mapping for `<CR>` that restores the original functionality:

```
:autocmd CmdwinEnter * noremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
```

This way, you can leave the plugin mapping alone, and do not need to duplicate its definition.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense. However this would work only in cmdwindow, what if there are other usecases where buftype is 'nofile', like coming from plugins...

Comment: Plugin scratch buffers wouldn't profit from the default behavior of `<CR>`, so if they offer functionality on that key, they have already provided such buffer-local mapping which eclipses the global one [from easymotion]. The issue mainly is only with the command-line window, because of the special built-in behavior of `<CR>`.

Comment: And again you right!

Comment: By any change do you know how to do the same for quickfix? `au BufEnter * if &l:buftype != 'nofile' && &ft != 'quickfix'` because this isnt' working for some reason.

Comment: @user1685095: I would use `:au FileType qf`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. Autocmd work, but even `unmap <CR> | noremap <buffer> <CR>` isn't. Easymotion still takes enter.

Comment: Okay, somehow I've tried it again and it works perfectly now.